# Convert SQL Query to MongoDB syntax

Tags: python, sql, mongodb

I have a big problem with converting SQL queries to Mongo DB for Python. I have a question if you know better methods for transferring SQL queries to Mongo DB queries?

I have two queries but I still have big problems with the syntax conversion to Mongo DB.
Maybe there is someone here who can help me?

Table

```
SELECT substring(CLIENT_ID, 1, 4) as SL , Avg(x) as x, Avg(y) as y 
FROM [SLOT_USE]
```

I have tried various converters but the result is poor.
Maybe there is some other method pandas or another faster tool?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I personally do not know of any good converters, It's just easier to understand each query and translate it on your own, especially as the queries you posted here are not too complex.

---

Query 1:

```
{
    id: "KVV",
    areo: "RSSO",
    sto: {$nin: ["AMA", "BR"]},
    use: 1
}
```

Combining with the "select" options:

```
db.prodw.find(
    {
        id: "KVV",
        areo: "RSSO",
        sto: {$nin: ["AMA", "BR"]},
        use: 1
    },
    {sto: 1, areo: 1, use: 1}
)
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/d0rWxMWpQ3p)

---

Query 2:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      CLIENT_ID: {
        $regex: "^(STK|CP1|LP1WA)"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: {
        "$substr": [
          "$CLIENT_ID",
          0,
          4
        ]
      },
      x: {
        $avg: "$x"
      },
      y: {
        $avg: "$y"
      },
      
    }
  },
  {
    $sort: {
      _id: 1
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      _id: 0,
      SL: "$_id",
      x: 1,
      y: 1
    }
  }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/rfcFVbk4q3M)

---

Comment: question, why do I have: "{$nin:"   '$'     -->SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: if you're using `python` all operators should be encased with ", meaning `$nin` should be `"$nin$"`. this is a python restriction unrelated to the MongDB language.

Comment: have this error, is there perhaps a more universal syntax ?:unknown operator: $nin$, full error: {'ok': 0.0, 'errmsg': 'unknown operator: $nin$', 'code': 2, 'codeName': 'BadValue'}

Comment: As you can see in the linked playground (https://mongoplayground.net/p/d0rWxMWpQ3p) the syntax is fine, just make sure you wrap every field and action name with `"`

Comment: Thanks again for your help, I added it to python, and it doesn't find me results, is it correct ? db.prodw.find(
    {
        "id": "KVV",
        "areo": "RSSO",
        "sto": {"$nin$": ["AMA", "BR"]},
        "use": 1
    },
    {"sto": 1, "areo": 1, "use": 1}
)

Comment: Yes, I recommend you play with the playground to understand the mongo syntax first, once you do it'll be easier to debug why your python app is not working properly. maybe the data in the db is in the wrong type? for example "use" could be saved as string and not as a number which will cause the query not to match any documents,